# Need to display the Mysql data as Order

Tags: mysql

Am having the chemical names data in mysql table like below, my tabe name is product master and column name is Name,   I want to display my output in an ascending order i.e, Atfirst Whatever the chemical name starts with 'A' chemical name will display first (for example Allyhydrazine dihydrochloride), then 'N'- chemical name followed by 'A' (for example N-Acetoxy-4-methoxyaniline) and atlast numerical chemical name(for example 6-Acetyloxy-  1-naphthoic acid) followed by 'A'

My previous output:

```
     Acetamide,  Acetoxyacetyl chloride,
6-Acetoxy-n-(4-chlorphenyl)-1-naphthamide, N-Acetoxy-4-methoxyaniline,
3-Acetoxy-2-methyl benzoic acid, Allyhydrazine dihydrochloride, 
(2Z)-2-Acetylamino-3-(biphenyl-4-yl)propenoic acid,
Aminonicotinic acid,  1-Acetyl-1,2-dihydro-3H-pyrazol-3-one, 
trans 4-(8-Amino-1-bromoimidazo[1,5-a]pyrazin-3-yl)
cyclohexanecarboxylic    acid, 1-Acetyl-6-fluoro-1H-indazole
Acetyl uracil, N-acetyl-4-(4-hydroxyphenyl)piperazine,
 6-Acetyloxy-  1-naphthoic acid, 
[(2-Aminoacetyl)amino]-3-(2-chlorobenzoyl)-6-ethox, 
3-Amino- 6-(aminomethyl)-1,2,4-triazin-5(4H)-one di,
Ammonium Phosphate, Acetelic Acid, 
2-Aminocarbonyl-3-nitrobenzoic acid,
 (5R,6S)-6-Amino-2,2-dimethyl-1,3-dioxepan-5-ol,
   Aminoimidazo[1,2-a]pyridine-6-carboxylic acid methyl ester
```

My expected Output:

```
    Acetamide, Allyhydrazine dihydrochloride,
    Ammonium Phosphate, Acetelic Acid,
    Aminoimidazo[1,2-a]pyridine-6-carboxylic acid methyl ester
    N-Acetoxy-4-methoxyaniline, N-acetyl-4-(4-hydroxyphenyl)piperazine,
    6-Acetoxy-n-(4-chlorphenyl)-1-naphthamide,
    3-Acetoxy-2-methyl benzoic acid, 
    3-Amino-6-(aminomethyl)-1,2,4-triazin-5(4H)-one di,
    2-Aminocarbonyl-3-nitrobenzoic acid
      (2Z)-2-Acetylamino-3-(biphenyl-4-yl)propenoic acid,
      trans 4-(8-Amino-1-bromoimidazo[1,5-a]pyrazin- 3-yl)cyclohexanecarboxylic acid
```

Note:

In my table contain all the chemical names starts with alphabets A to Z. when i typing A,  i want to display results as Chemical Name starts with A (Ammino Acid), N followed by alphabets A chemical names (for example N-Acetoxy-4-methoxyaniline), numbers followed by A chemical Names (for example 6-Acetoxy-n-(4-chlorphenyl)-1-naphthamide), (2N) or (4N) followed by A chemical names (for example 2Z)-2-Acetylamino-3-(biphenyl-4-yl)propenoic acid) and trans with start by A chemical Names (for example trans 4-(8-Amino-1-bromoimidazo[1,5-a]pyrazin-3-yl)cyclohexanecarboxylic acid) , and When i searching B it should the results as same as A chemical Names

Comment: The chemical name is not consistent and will be hard to order without using a custom function IMHO. How many records does your table have? And what is the maximum length of name?

Comment: This is probably most easily resolved in your application code

Comment: Heard of TypeAhead.js ? - https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: I would suggest to go with MySql `views` as you would be **reading** table data more than inserting into the table. But again no one can help you with the **exact** function since what you are asking for is huge. One has to know about all possible combinations to get a function which sorts in the order you are asking for. Unfortunately, I think only you will have to figure it out by trial and error.

Comment: am trying this query                                                                                 SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX('-', Name) +1, 100)), Name from productmaster

WHERE  LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX('-', Name) +1, 100)) LIKE 'a%'
 order by 1;

Comment: but not getting output